# Date format in JQuery from JSON Data

Tags: jquery

How to have the output of my JSON Date value as follows in JQuery?
'11/25/2011 10:43:45 AM'

Comment: Datetime format of SQL Server

Comment: Which is ....... and what language are you using to get from SQL to the browser ? there are lots of ways to skin a cat

Comment: There is no inbuilt method in jQuery to change the format of a date - but there are in SQL / MySQL / PHP / .NET / Java ... ie they are more suited to change the format of a date .... (im not saying it cant be done in JavaScript)

Comment: like Date.Now in Asp.net and I want to format it like '11/25/2011 10:43:45 AM'

Comment: I dont use SQL server and i dont use Asp.net - just **please** update your question with the format of the date you want to translate !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the date as a date type, but for display I tend to just get the date into the string format I like on JSON source and pass it to the client like that, ie: rather than let the date be serialized into '/Date(1224043200000)/' I pass DateTime.Now.ToString().

If you can't do that [How to Format a JSON date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) might help?

Comment: Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt")

Answer (score 2):

You could try datejs - http://www.datejs.com/

You can see a full list of the formats it provides here - http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Comment: I will, I like to use the client side resources than the server side, but for now I didn't want to use external JS in my project and use the server side formatting instead.